# Faking email domain names

Tags: email-spoofing

My organisation uses the following domain name '@organisation.org.au' to specify emails that have originated from within the organisation.

Is it possible to use an online tool to create a fake email with the same domain name?

I.e. : LegitimateUser@organisation.org.au (Created from the organisation's mail server)

```
 : FakeUser@organisation.org.au (Created from a mailbox outside of the organisation)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. The SMTP protocol allows to set any sender address you want when sending emails. However, they will very likely be rejected as spam because most mailservers are configured to only accept mails from other mailservers when the sender address matches the domain of the mailserver.

Answer (score 0):

`Yes, it possible . Sending email from *@ogranization.org without having access to the domain is a type of attack popular called email spoofing` ,

> There are a lot of case where victim will targeted sending email seems
>   to be from the valid domain with malicious virus ,RAT  but they are
>   not.

,So most of the time  spam filter engine of the email provider will detect it but there are also ways to make it undetectable. So only a easy way to detect check out the ip headers of the sender if it match the ip of the real organization and alot off parameter which can help find it is fake here a example of header info OR You can check it out at

From  http://www.howtogeek.com/108205/htg-explains-what-can-you-find-in-an-email-header/

```
for <jason@myemail.com>; Tue, 6 Mar 2012 19:27:05 +0700
To: <jason@myemail.com>
Subject: Your Intuit.com invoice.
**X-PHP-Script: intuit.com/sendmail.php for 118.68.152.212**
```